# Are unupvotes serial voting?

Tags: feature-request, serial-voting

[This user](https://stackoverflow.com/users/573032/roman-c?tab=reputation) lost **300 rep** from unupvotes today *.

- Is this considered serial voting?
- Is this allowed?
- Does the serial-vote-reversal-script notice that since it is taking votes back instead of downvoting?

<sub>* A user edited the answers to retract the votes</sub>

Comment: Definitely looks like serial voting and no, it is not allowed.

Comment: Does the script notice that since it is taking votes back instead of downvoting?

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't. Yet.

Answer (score 30):

This certainly falls under serial voting.

The votes are un-upvotes, but they are voting behavior non the less. And they are targeted at specific users, not the content.

As such this goes against the rules - it is not allowed in any shape or form.

The reversal script doesn't handle this specific kind of case at the moment, but we may very well add it.

Comment: Until it is implemented, do we flag any post or add here on Meta?

Comment: @hims056 - Flag any post - this is rather unusual - first time I have seen it.

Comment: Also see my comments on the question as I'm somewhat involved.

Comment: So would you call this oscillation?

Comment: @BoltClock'saUnicorn - I may, I may not.

Comment: @BoltClock'saUnicorn: definitely Oscillation. And 4-8 weeks too (4 in this case) :)

Comment: @AndreaLigios - With regards to the downvotes, the script didn't revert them. Probably because they were not serial downvotes.

Comment: Was this added?

Comment: Has this been added? Because I've been a victim of this on M&TV over the last three months.

Comment: @cde - not seeing signs of many unupvotes there on your user.

Comment: @oded aside from the 4 over two minutes today/yesterday, there are many more spaced out. I'll grab a few screenshots in a minute.

Comment: I see serial *downvotes*, not serial unpvotes. Different things, @cde

Comment: 4 here https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2854/ 2 here https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2812/ and 3 here https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2811/ and that's not including the un-upvotes that are by themselves, 1 one day, another the next, another two days after that.

Comment: @ODED and two more serial un-upvotes just now. I'm guessing that adding checks for this type of abuse just never got added to the to-do list, in 4+ years of people requesting it?