# Users with answer editing privileges should be able to change their votes on answers

Tags: discussion, feature-request, answers, voting, privileges

Sometimes info in a comment causes me to want to retract a downvote on an answer.

It's not possible to change a vote once its locked in unless the answer is edited, but since I can edit answers, its easy enough to work around this by e.g. adding a dummy HTML comment to the answer.

Some day, my dummy workaround comments will conquer SO.

It seems like, given that nothing actually prevents a person who can edit an answer from harmlessly editing the answer to change their vote, that it would make sense to just allow you to change your vote if you have answer editing privileges.

Comment: If you edit to unlock your votes, you leave a trail of evidence in case your voting pattern needs to be punished

Comment: Not everyone would want to follow that path of editing an answer in order to change their vote. Why code for this `not so frequent` practice?

Comment: *"Some day, my dummy workaround comments will conquer SO."* .... Some day, I will hunt you down and smack you with your own hands while yelling "stop hitting yourself" if you keep doing that .... :)

Comment: Well, it doesn't happen as often as I implied. I'd say about once per week. It would be a very slow conquering. I'm an upstanding citizen, I have nothing to hide.

Comment: Once a week? That's a _lot_.

Comment: Considering I'm active enough to hit the rep cap on almost every day that I visit, that seems like a reasonable rate for the pattern: Downvote poor/misunderstood answer => clarification/justification in comment changes quality to a 0 instead of -1 => remove downvote. You may be misunderstanding my motivations. My general criteria, fwiw, is downvote misleading/incorrect, novote informative-but-unhelpful, upvote helpful/correct. I would be equally happy if users with edit privileges could simply uncast downvotes.

Comment: @JasonC if the answer is misleading without its comments, perhaps those comments should be incorporated into the answer body. Thus, when I change my mind, normally I have a reason to edit, too.

Comment: you are voting on the quality of the answer not a comment. If you once decide to downvote an answer then that's the part you're voting on. If you think a comment adds value to the answer then upvote the comment. You can leave a suggestion to the answerer to update his answer but if you do it yourself you expose your identity to the community almost asking for a revenge war... :P

Comment: @JanDvorak I would argue that your apparent practice of making radical changes to others' answers based on the comments is more unsavory than my practice of sometimes removing a downvote.

Comment: @mehow That's a good point, although I can't imagine a revenge war starting because I uncast my downvote. Can you?

Comment: @JasonC I meant: to edit or to suggest the answerer does.

Comment: @JasonC sure I can. Should I dig that up?

Comment: @JanDvorak yes, actually, if you have it handy. Mostly because now I'm intrigued.

Comment: @JasonC voting should always remain anonymous. quick scenario - you uncast your vote and someone else gets downvoted on their answer - you become a target...

Comment: @mehow If you mean "exposing my identity as the downvoter" I already do that by explaining my downvotes when I make them. I hope you do the same.

Comment: I think showing a little bit of maturity and leaving a reasonable explanation for a downvote alleviates that "problem" entirely. :P

Comment: I don't always explain my downvotes on questions. But when I do, my comments are always canned (just kidding)

Comment: @JasonC i dont really downvote  answers unless i am sure theyre completely wrong and there is no point of keeping the answer. In such cases I downvote, and flag for deletion and most of the time the answer actually does get deleted so I am not facing the exact same issue as you are which is just disagreement I think

Comment: Me neither, I'm talking specifically about answers, not questions. The topic of my OP was answers, never questions.

Comment: I usually explain my answer downvotes or upvote an existing comment.

Comment: @JanDvorak :) I was addressing mehow's comment about the "risk" of revealing my identity as a downvoter by stating that I thought it was moot for the way I use the system, as I dont use the flags much on answers, and generally always immediately and explicitly identify myself when downvoting an answer anyways. Also it wouldn't particularly irritate me if somebody took "revenge" on me, I don't think...

Comment: I don't have the time to write out an answer, but here's a record of the incident: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/199946/are-unupvotes-serial-voting

Comment: That's not a "revenge war". It's also, if you really think about it, completely inconsequential that a user "serial unupvoted". I'm not sure why they put time into automated protection against it. Why do we care?

Comment: @JasonC "I would argue that your apparent practice of making radical changes to others' answers based on the comments" An edit that merely takes an authors views in comments and moved them into the post itself, given that they have been determined to be relevant, is not a "radical edit".  A "radical edit" is adding content that the author of the post didn't contribute themselves; since you're adding content that they contributed, the edit is not radical, nor is it inappropriate.  In fact, that type of edit is *encouraged* in the editing guidelines.

Comment: @Servy Based on the votes I consistently see in the suggested edit queue, you may want to start thinking of ways to educate the community on that guideline. Also it doesn't help that the edit review doesn't display comments.

Comment: @JasonC All it takes is a revision note of "moving comments from the author into the post".  When such a revision note is there, they are approved reasonably often, although this isn't something I see a whole lot of in general.  Regardless, the situation you're talking about is with a 2k+ user, so they need not worry about reviewers rejecting a valid edit.

Comment: @Servy Sure. Consistent high quality revision notes. That happens. /sarcasm. But yes -- I digressed there, sorry. Doesn't apply to 2k users.

Comment: If a user makes an edit that is not clear it is their responsibility to use a proper revision notation to clarify.  If they don't, that is their responsibility for having the edit rejected.  If they *do* include an effective notation, then it is the reviewers responsibility to read it and take it into consideration.

Comment: @servy ot: That's valid. I personally believe that it's the reviewers additional responsibility to look past a crappy revision note if the edit is good, looking at context to decide if that's the case, especially given typical revision note quality. That's my opinion. Although for the case we are talking about, at the moment it's very inconvenient to do that (at least until answer comments are displayed in reviews).

Comment: Even if comments are displayed, I consider it overly burdensome on the reviewer to read through the *entire* comment thread to look for any possible comments including the relevant information.  Many comment threads that end up generating information worth editing in can be fairly long.  On top of that, *most* questions won't require looking through comments, and most additions of new content are based on comments; this is consuming a *lot* of extra reviewer time.  It is the responsibility of the editor to do their job well enough that little time is consumed by the reviewer.

Comment: If the reviewers end up spending way more time reviewing posts than the editors do suggesting them then the system isn't really serving a purpose; those reviewers could have just gone and spend their time editing posts instead.  The entire suggested edit system is only a "win" if the lower rep users end up saving time from the higher rep users.

Comment: Still ot: If you really think about the process there, if a user merges comments into an answer and doesn't leave a good revision note, then the edit gets rejected, I don't believe it's likely that the user will go back and resubmit the edit with a better note. In facts, they'd probably just stop making such edits in the future, seeing that the rejection reason was "too radical", and not associating that with the true problem: their nondescriptive summary. Then, in a larger sense, this is damaging, as a good edit is forever lost to the community, *and* users stop making that type of edit.

Comment: As for "spending more time" yes that's exactly my point about the comments not currently being displayed. :) What I'm saying here is that in general, quality is lost. For edits that merge comments: Revision notes typically nondescriptive + no comments displayed + reviewers wanting to be efficient = potentially good edits that get rejected with no good quick way to determine that they were actually valid = difficult for me to live up to what I think are my responsibilities as a reviewer. If that makes sense... Sorry, that was a hard thought to put into writing.

Comment: Also re: Time spent reviewing comments, don't forget that if a comment is worth merging, we hope it's received upvotes. Then it is more likely to be readily visible.

Answer (score 1):

Allowing for a change in vote based on whether the post has been edited is to enable the voter to evaluate the updated post.  It isn't intended to allow the voter to change their mind.  In fact, that's why votes get locked in the first place.  I'd consider this abuse.

That said, I did mistakenly downvote a new user without understanding the question.  In order to rectify the error, I edited their post then upvoted.

Answer (score -1):

Comments are second class citizens.

You should vote on the answer, without taking into account the comments (possibly with some minor exceptions).

If something said in a comment led to you wanting to retract your downvote (such as a clarification of a misunderstanding, or an elaboration), this should probably be incorporated into the answer, either by you (if it's not a major edit), or by the author.

This edit will allow you to retract your vote.

So no, I don't think this is a good reason to allow retracting of votes.

The workaround also generally isn't particularly appropriate (side note - why not just add a line break somewhere instead of a dummy comment?).

If you would've gone for "sometimes you're just in a bad mood", maybe I would've agreed with that.

**General advice to largely avoid the need for this:** Comment first, wait a bit, then downvote.